# The product of two sequences where one is bounded and the other is convergent to zero

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I'm trying to prove, given only that one sequence $B$ is bounded and the other sequence $A$ is convergent to zero, that their product also converges.

My work probably wouldn't be considered a formal proof but I'm curious if my strategy/thought process is on the right track.

My work:

Since $A$ converges to zero, there exists a point in this sequence where all terms are between $-1$ and $1$.
In this case, whatever behavior $B$ has will be dictated by the terms of $A$.
If $B=0$, then the conclusion is trivial.
Thus, $AB$ converges to zero.

Comment: What do you mean by 'B is bounded'? For example, $\ln x$ is bounded by $y=x$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, and $e^{-x}$ converges to $0$, but the limit to infinity of $\ln x \cdot e^{-x}$ is $+\infty$.

Comment: Hint: If $(b_n)$ is a bounded sequence, i.e. there exists an $M>0$ such that $|b_n|\le M$ for all $n\ge 1$. This gives $|b_na_n|\le M|a_n|$.

Comment: By bounded I mean that a supremum and an infimum exists for the sequence. Basically, that it doesn't just go off to infinity. But thank you both for the comments I think I'm getting a clearer picture of what is going on.

Comment: the problem with your idea is that "dictated" doesnt have an specific meaning, and also the bound of $A$ to values in $[-1,1]$ doesnt says something about the convergence of $AB$. If $B$ is bounded and $A$ is also bounded this doesnt means that $AB$ converges. By example the sequence $-1,1,-1,1,\ldots$ is bounded but it is not convergent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a formal one: Let $M>0$ be such that $|y_{n}|\leq M$. Let $\{x_{n}\}$ be such that $x_{n}\rightarrow 0$. Given $\epsilon>0$, for the positive number $\epsilon/M$, there exists some $N$ such that $|x_{n}|<\epsilon/M$ for all $n\geq N$, so $|x_{n}y_{n}|\leq M|x_{n}|<M\cdot\epsilon/M=\epsilon$ for all such $n$, this shows that $x_{n}y_{n}\rightarrow 0$.